# FileNotFoundException In OAuth2 With Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I have implemented an authorization-server application with spring security and using a private key to sign the token. The generated asymmetric key is stored in the resource path on the application. when I run the application the following error has occurred.

**error**

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [jwt.jks] cannot be opened because it does not exist

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tokenStore' defined in class path resource [com/benz/oauth2/api/config/AuthorizationServerConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore]: Factory method 'tokenStore' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtAccessTokenConverter' defined in class path resource [com/benz/oauth2/api/config/AuthorizationServerConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter]: Factory method 'jwtAccessTokenConverter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load keys from store: class path resource [jwt.jks]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
```

**AuthorizationServer class**

```
@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore()
{
 return new JwtTokenStore(jwtAccessTokenConverter());
}


public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter=new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    converter.setKeyPair(new KeyStoreKeyFactory(new ClassPathResource("jwt.jks"),"1429Oop".toCharArray()).getKeyPair("springblog"));
    return converter;
}
```

**Note** - jwt.jks is stored under the resource path

Comment: could you check in the project build directory, whether the jwt.jks file is in the class folder

Comment: yes. it is not available in the build directory. should I have to paste it explicitly into the build directory

Comment: if it is in the class folder it will be loaded. You need to figure out the reason for not copying the jwt.jks file from resources folder to   build classes folder.
I think, you will have to check build tool configuration.

Comment: thanks. clean the build and installed it then it was added to the build directory